# Angular Text Cursor Moved Event on Mobile

Tags: html, ios, angular, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm building an Ionic app using Angular 4 and I would like to know when the text cursor is moved on mobile. Here's an example in the Evernote mobile app. Notice the bold/italic/underline buttons change on cursor move:

[image: Evernote example]

I've tried all of the event handlers on the [Document interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) to no avail, at least on iOS. How can I capture when the cursor is moved?